# 3 rules don't work together (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried some different things but can't get this working.

What my code should do:

1. remove `www`
2. use `https`
3. if the url doesn't exist go to `index.php`

1&2 work for me
3 works for me
But when I add 1,2 & 3 together I get an error.

My code is:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you @Paradox for clearing my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R=301,END]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=301,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ index.php [NS,END]
```

Using a base is a good idea. Extra groups are not needed in PCRE. Only redirect non-empty URLs as you likely have `index.php` in your `DirectoryIndex` already.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It makes an error when i go to domain/xxx - it should go to index.php

Comment: Do you get the same error if you visit the `index.php` file, directly? What about if you redirect to a temporary, static `.html` file?

Comment: domain.xxx works (index.php) ---
domain.xxx/index.php works ----
domain.xxx/file.html is not working, it redirect to index.php - the file exist ---
domain.xxx/somefake is not working - 404 "The requested URL /asd was not found on this server."

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest merging the rules to force HTTPs and remove WWW. Would remove the need for an extra rule to be run and speed up server response.

Comment: Can you give me an exsample? :)

Comment: @thickguru merging the rules will have no performance gain; both conditions are still tested on every request, anyway. There are no redirects to non-https.

Comment: I suspect there is some other configuration/issue interfering with your request+response cycle, either at the vhost level or above. You need to eliminate it by commenting out things until you find the cause.